# Using a custom `glance` method in huxtable::huxreg()

Tags: r, lme4, broom, huxtable

I am looking for a way to report the number of groups alongside the number of observations using `huxtable::huxreg` to create a table of results of a multilevel model predicted with `lmer()`. I can write a custom glance method that overwrites the `glance.merMod` method from the `broom.mixed` package that works when called from R but does not work when calling `huxreg()`.

I believe that the issue is that the huxreg function imports both `broom` and `broom.mixed` as required namespaces [inside the function](https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/blob/7be99e7672fe6ee41ca0bd72427ace0acc45496e/R/huxreg.R#L127).

What would be the best way to overcome this issue to use the custom glance method (or an alternative other than simply adding rows to existing huxtables)?

Here's a MWE

```
library(lme4)
library(tibble)
library(huxtable)
library(broom.mixed)

## Simulate multilevel data
sigma <- 0.5
tau <- 0.1
x <- rnorm(100)
w <- rep(rnorm(10), each=10); i <- factor(rep(1:10, each=10))
y <- x + w + rep(rnorm(10, 0, tau), each = 10) + rnorm(100, 0, sigma)
d <- tibble(y, x, w)
m <- lmer(y ~ x + w + (1|i), data=d)

## Custom glance method
glance.merMod <- function(x, ret=tibble::tibble_row()) {
    ret$nobs <- nobs(x)
    ret$ngrps <- summary(x)$ngrps
    return(ret)
}

glance(m) ## Works, returns nobs and ngrps
huxreg(m, statistics = c("nobs", "ngrps")) ## Doesn't work, ngrps missing
```

Comment: You may want to look at `tidy_override`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this using `tidy_override()`:

```
m2 <- tidy_override(m, 
        glance = list(
          ngrps = summary(m)$ngrps
        ), 
        extend = TRUE
      )
huxreg(m2, statistics = c("nobs", "ngrps"))

       ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                          (1)           
                               ─────────────────────────
         (Intercept)                            0.027   
                                               (0.064)  
         x                                      0.916   
                                               (0.063)  
         w                                      0.982   
                                               (0.075)  
         sd__(Intercept)                        0.096   
                                             (NA)       
         sd__Observation                        0.561   
                                             (NA)       
                               ─────────────────────────
         nobs                                 100       
         ngrps                                 10.000   
       ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
         *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.
```

You'll probably also want to call `set_number_format` on the `ngrps` cell.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you! I wasn't adding the `extend` option, which is why I couldn't get `tidy_override()` to work. I appreciate your example!

Comment: (BTW, there is a close-parens missing at the end of the huxreg command -- I tried to edit, but couldn't)